# Using WQL to Limit Results on a String Match

Tags: wmi, wql

I'm working on developing a WMI query for my application.  It needs to find the assigned virtual COM port for a given VID/PID.  My query currently looks like this:

```
"SELECT DeviceID FROM Win32_SerialPort WHERE PNPDeviceID = \"USB\\VID_10C4&PID_EA60\\0001\""
```

Based on my research, it should return `"COM8"`.  However, I'm getting an empty set.

Are string comparisons valid in WQL?  As I recall, SQL allows them, but being a subset, I'm not sure if support for them was carried over.

If necessary, I suppose I can query `"SELECT DeviceID,PNPDeviceID FROM Win32_SerialPort"` and then in code parse through the results using string compares, but I'd prefer to limit the results in the query, if possible.

Additionally, I was wondering, if string compares are indeed supported in WQL, are they case sensitive, and/or is there a way to specify case?

Thanks.

Comment: @Garett: This question is purely about WMI and WQL.  The same query can be as easily implemented in C#, C++, or any other language that can access WMI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this (C#):

```
"Select * From Win32_SerialPort Where PnPDeviceId = \"PCI\\\\VEN_14F1&DEV_2F30&SUBSYS_205D14F1&REV_01\\\\4&1F7DBC9F&0&10F0\""
```

I needed to escape the backslashes once for WMI's sake and once again for C#'s sake, so I ended with quadruple backslashes in the query.